# Cannot connect IBOutlet to a UIViewController (or subclass thereof)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

I am currently trying to build a demo app in Xcode 8.2.1 using swift to learn how to use UIPageViewController.  I added three outlets to my subclass of UIPageViewController which I intended to connect to the three views that the page view controller would control.

```
class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
  @IBOutlet weak var redController : MyColorViewController!
  @IBOutlet weak var greenController : MyColorViewController!
  @IBOutlet weak var blueController : MyColorViewController!
  //...
}
```

In my main storyboard, I created one instance of MyPageViewController and three instances of MyColorViewController.

But, for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get the storyboard to connect the three outlets above to any of the color view controller instances.

[image: controller instances]

I have tried both ctrl-dragging from the page view controller itself to each color view controller and from the page view controller's outlets in the inspector.  Nothing works.

[image: attempt to connect page controller to blue controller]

Suggestions?

Comment: You cannot connect `UIViewControllers` as `@IBOutlets`. What is it you are trying to do? Each View Controller in a storyboard is a self-contained item. IBOutlets can onnly be things "inside" the view controller "scene".

Comment: You should drage from `blueController` to the blue view *controller*, not to the blue *view*

Comment: @MikeMayer97 HERE IS THE EXACT SAME THING -: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/12/23/swift-uipageviewcontroller-tutorial/

Comment: @Andreas... tried that too, didn't work either (as other responders indicated should be the case)

Comment: @Tushar... funny that you should point me to that site.  That was what I was walking through.  I was trying to see if I couldn't replace the programmatic connections using storyboard.  Turns out I was running down a bad path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this by code. And not with IBOutlets.

First: set a storyboard ID to each of the UIViewControllers.

Second:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"blueViewController") as! UIViewController
```

And connect it to a property.

You do this for all three UIViewControllers.

Comment: Thank you.   I was able to do it in code.  I was trying to see if I could use the storyboard instead.   Looks like that was a non-starter.

Comment: @MikeMayer67 Glad to help, This is the way to go and makes things much cleaner and easy managed.